# How to filter GridTemplateColumns of Telerik's RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, filtering, radgrid

I have two `GridTemplateColumn`s in my `RadGrid`. The default filtering doesn't work for me and I want to change it.

The GridTemplateColumns are like below:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter Online column" HeaderText="Online"
    UniqueName="Online">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOnline" runat="server" Checked='<%# CheckForOnline(Eval("ID")) %>'
            Enabled="False" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="100px" />
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

and the other one:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter FileSize column" HeaderText="FileSize"
    UniqueName="FileSize" Visible="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFileSize" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FileSize") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter FileSizeChange column" HeaderText="FileSize"
    UniqueName="FileSizeChange">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFileSizeChange" runat="server" Text='<%# ChangeFileSize(Eval("FileSize")) %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

As you can see, `FileSize` `TemplateColumn` is disabled and I am using `FileSizeChange` instead.

FileSize string is like (213435) -> this number shows us bytes. FileSizeChange is like (231 MB)/

How can I write filtering for both `Online` and `FileSizeChange` `GridTemplateColumn`s?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use filtering on a Template column you need to set the **DataField** and add the datafield to the DataKeyNames

eg:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowFilteringByColumn="True">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID">
        <Columns> 
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="ID" FilterControlAltText="Filter Online column" HeaderText="Online" UniqueName="Online">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOnline" runat="server" Checked='<%# CheckForOnline(Eval("ID")) %>' Enabled="False" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="100px" />
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
...
etc, etc
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need filtering on an item template column make sure you set the following properties on the item template column:

`DataField="FileSize"
AllowFiltering="true"
AutoPostBackOnFilter="true"
DataType="System.String"`

These two are optional if you want to hide the filter function icon:
`ShowFilterIcon="false"
CurrentFilterFunction="Contains"`

Also make sure you have filtering enabled on your radgrid.

Here's a good post about it:
http://www.telerikschool.com/2011/11/textbox-in-gridtemplatecolumn.html

Answer (score 1):

Because this is an ItemTemplate that you're building manually, you will need to filter manually. See this page of the Telerik docs: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-operate-with-filter-expression-manually.html